# JS Regex: Match a string if it is not in quotes, which may or may not be closed

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regex to match, for example, '0' characters.
But, I only want to match 0's that are not in quotes, which may not be closed.

Here's an example of an input string, and the 0's that I want to match are indicated.

```
abc"0
"hi 0 bye
"00
0 //match here
If 0 //match here
If (00) //match here, with both zeros being in the same capture group.
hell0 w0rld //match here, each zero being different
"0"
"00"
5*0 // match here
00 //match here, with both zeros being in the same capture group.
```

I have tried modifying snippets on other threads, but to no avail.
Primarily,  I though I could change `(?!\B"[^"]*)0(?![^"]*"\B)` (posted on another thread) to fit my needs, but I was unable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
^[^"]*?(0+)[^"]*?$
```

should work.

This is basically match a line that contains 0 and does not contain quotes. The zero is captured within a group.

```js
let str = `abc"0
"hi 0 bye
"00
0 //match here
If 0 //match here
If (00) //match here, with both zeros being in the same capture group.
hell0 w0rld //match here, each zero being different
"0"
"00"
5*0 // match here
00 //match here, with both zeros being in the same capture group.`

str.split("\n").forEach(s => console.log((/^[^"]*?(0+)[^"]*?$/g).exec(s)));
```

Comment: Thanks! That’s really obvious, too. Be sure to add a greedy operator to the zero, so that it gets all of the available zeros, right?

Comment: Good point! Updated to work with the examples with more than 1 zero in there.